# can AJAX do anything else than load a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, processwire

I'm want to (or think I need to) use AJAX to accomplish what I intend.

When clicking on a specific link in a list of links, I want to fill the HTML markup below with content of specific subpages. The data is naturally somewhere in the database and actually easily accessible with the CMS's API (**I'm using Processwire**).

I'm quite new to coding and especially AJAX and **all documentation I find online only mention it in combination with a JSON file** that would be loaded via AJAX.

However, I don't have a JSON file on the server, that means, according to my understanding, I would need to

1. store the data I need in a multidimensional php array,
2. use json_decode to create and then save that JSON-file on the server,
3. load that file via AJAX and process through more JS.

Let alone keep that JSON-file updated (or create a new one and delete the old one?) since new content will arrive periodically. It seems unnecessarily complicated to me, but what do I know.

There's got to be a better way…
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 2 . just json_encode your data array and directly send the result as the response to the ajax request. No need to create a file. Json is basically just formatted text.

Comment: AJAX is just another way to run a HTTP request. So you can send or receive any type of data you want, same as in any other type of HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is simply a way to make a request to the web server for information.

When you make an AJAX request you ask for a response from a file on a server. So, you can send an AJAX request to a PHP script for-instance.

The PHP script could return anything, JSON is common and very widely used response format, but XML might be another one you've encountered.

So, your request for information is made using AJAX, and the response you get back is JSON.

You don't need to store a JSON file on your server. You just need to make an AJAX request that returns current data in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX allows you to do asynchronous HTTP requests.

You can of course ask for a json file, but you can also (for example) call an API.

I suggest you start by reading the the getting started guide for AJAX in MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started